# breadcrumbs_on_rails rendering twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, breadcrumbs

I am trying to get my breadcrumbs to follow my navigation history through different controllers

Application Controller

```
add_breadcrumb 'Home', root_path
```

In my public_pages controller

```
class PublicPagesController < ApplicationController


def index

end

def news
 add_breadcrumb "News", news_path
 add_breadcrumb "Contact us", contact_path
end

def contact_us
add_breadcrumb "News", news_path
add_breadcrumb "Contact us", contact_path
end
```

so i have another controller called private_pages which is only accessible when a user logs in, and this has its own root_path,

How would i show breadcrumbs when accessing different actions in different controllers

Thanks

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? You are calling `add_breadcrumb` 4 times, and it is rendering twice as expected (Home / News / Home / News). Is that correct? Could you elaborate on the 'history' issue?

Comment: no, first question then is do i only call the add_breadcrumb in the action or on top of the controller, the docs seem to indicate that you add it to the stack at the top then call each individual action.

Comment: You should just add it in the actions. The controller level calls will run on every action, and so cause duplicates if you have calls in the actions too.

Comment: ah right, so am i right in thinking that if i navigated from home to contact us, then the breadcrumb trail should look like this Home / Contact us.. because if it does then that is not happening for me

Comment: Sorry, I'll add my answer now with the proper usage. What gem are you using btw?

Comment: thank you very much, I am using gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails", I am also using Twitter bootstrap, does this make a difference? I have read that there are naming conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the `home` breadcrumb to your `ApplicationController` as that should be registered for *every* request. If your application is not publicly accessible in this regard, then disregard that, and keep the `home` breadcrumb in your `PublicPagesController` before the methods.

Then, update your `PublicPagesController`:

```
class PublicPagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def news
    # to show Home / Contact Us / News
    add_breadcrumb "Contact Us", news_path
    add_breadcrumb "News", news_path
  end

  def contact_us
    add_breadcrumb "Contact Us", news_path
  end

end
```

The above assumes that `add_breadcrumb "Home", news_path` is called in your `ApplicationController`.

In regards to `bootstrap` conflicts or integration, see these two:

https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails/issues/24
https://gist.github.com/2400302

If you want to amend the `home` breadcrumb based on whether user is logged in or not, add a `before_filter` to your `ApplicationController`:

```
before_filter :set_home_breadcrumb

def set_home_breadcrumb
  if user_signed_in?
    add_breadcrumb "Home", :user_home_path
  else
    add_breadcrumb "Home", :root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but still it doesn’t follow my route, ie Home / Contact Us  so its not keeping my navigation history, it does do this i guess? Also i have setup a .rb file like in the gisthub example

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'navigation history'? With the above in place, you should at least see "Home / News" without duplicate crumbs.

Comment: well if i am on the home page it should show Home as my breadcrumb. when i navigate to contact Us then i would expect Home / Contact Us, if i then navigated to News i would expect Home / Contact Us / News and to answer your question yes i can see Home / Contact Us at the moment

Comment: Is your contact_us method under the same controller? If you want news to come after Contact Us, then you will need to add both contact us and news to that action. I'll update my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: yes in this case they are under the same controller, so what happens if i want to add breadcrumbs in different controllers? apologies for all the questions, and thank you for your help

Comment: From my experience with the gem, most of it is manual `add_breadcrumb` calls. You could possibly avoid this by adding a before_filter to the ApplicationController and dynamically generating the breadcrumbs based on controller/action, but with custom order (Contact Us / News), you'd need to map it out.

Comment: If you update your question with a more complex example of your breadcrumbs I'll update my answer with a suggestion of how to handle it effectively.

Comment: ah right i think i see how the breadcrumbs work in the same controller at least, so each action refers the all the other actions within the controller, so if i had 10 actions then each action would have 10 add_breadcrumb calls, so that all actions can reference each other..hope that makes sense, i will update question now

Comment: It depends. If you wanted a particular actions breadcrumb to be routed under other actions, then yes, you'd have to register each of those breadcrumbs. But I don't see any logical reason for this - pages are top level. Contact Us -> News doesn't seem correct. It is your application though, so I could be overlooking something.

Comment: I have found though that if i dont declare as i have then i dont get the history of my navigation in the breadcrumbs, just whatever page I am on then the breadcrumb matches

Comment: That is the idea of breadcrumbs though. That it shows a logical hierarchy of links. If `Contact Us / News` is show on `news page`, then `contact us` page should not show `News` in breadcrumbs, but you have added it under that method. I've updated my answer to show how you might amend the Home breadcrumb for logged in users.

Comment: thanks for your help, ill have a play and see what i can get to work, then refactor afterwards

Comment: No worries. let me know if you struggle further. Have a look at application helpers to aid you in generating breadcrumbs automatically where possible. Much better than littering your code with `add_breadcrumb` calls.

Comment: sorry another question, you mentioned logical hierarchy of links, if i navigate from home /News / Our services / Contact Us is there a reason why these wouldnt all show in the breadcrumb links, our services goes missing in my case, i have reduced the add_breadcrumb to one per action, ie news in news, our services in our services

Comment: Sorry, I think I see where the confusion is. You want a list of breadcrumbs based on how the user reached that page, not static, which is what the gem does. I don't believe there is a general solution for this as it is quite a rare requirement.

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want :), so this gem isnt what i am looking for then, sorry for the confusion.maybe there is a jquery plugin available

Comment: One way of achieving that is storing the users history in a session, or yes, using a jquery plugin and storing a session that way. Edit: see here for info: https://github.com/dkeener/active_breadcrumbs -- "(as opposed to a "dynamic" trail, which reflects where the user has been - for which I humbbly suggest the user take advantage of the browser's Back button)."